# Search table multiple columns on variable number of parameters

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I have a search input box where a user can enter one or more word and the php script should return all the row where all those words are include in any column.

Suppose a table like this:

```
|car_id|make|model|year|plate|
+----------------------------+
|  1   |Audi|A4   |2010|AAAAA|
|  2   |Audi|A4   |2012|AAAAB|
|  3   |Audi|Q5   |2010|AAAAC|
+----------------------------+
```

If a user enter "Aud", he get the 3 rows. If it enter "2010 Audi", he get row 1 and 3, and if he enter "Aud q5 2010", he get only row 3.

**What I have done.**

If the input as only 1 term, i can build a query like

```
SELECT * FROM car WHERE make LIKE '%term%' OR model like '%term%' OR year like '%term%'
```

If the user enter 2 terms, I have to create this query instead (even don't consider the plate column)

```
SELECT * FROM car WHERE 
     (make LIKE '%term%' AND model LIKE '%term2%') 
  OR (make LIKE '%term2%' AND model LIKE '%term%')
  OR (make LIKE '%term%' AND year LIKE '%term2%')
  OR (make LIKE '%term1%' AND year LIKE '%term%')
  OR (model LIKE '%term%' AND year LIKE '%term%')
  OR (model LIKE '%term2%' AND year LIKE '%term1%')
```

If a user enter 3 terms, the query get exponentialy more complexe.

I read about MATCH keyword but some column are not text, like year in this exemple.

What is the correct way to do this kind of search? Should I change database schema?  Concat all searchable columns into a string and do some regex,

Thank you.

Comment: The easiest solution for this would be to have separate year, make, and model text inputs that the user enters their criteria into. This way when you receive the request you know which columns you need to search through based on what was provided.

Comment: The same search box wil be used for other table too. and I think that is more user friendly to have a simple google like search box than many input control.

Comment: How are you distinguishing between "terms", are you simply parsing the user input string and `exploding()` it on space so that each word in the box that is separated by a space is considered a separate term? Which would in theory mean there could be 10 - 20 - 100 different terms?

Comment: Yes, explode on space. I can limit the term to 3 (the first 3) because that 's enough for my current scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create an extra column, `all`.  Have it contain the `CONCAT_WS(' ', ...)` of all the columns you need to search on.
2. Create a `FULLTEXT(all)` index on that column.
3. Construct the query with just one clause:

   `WHERE MATCH(all) AGAINST("+Audi +q5 +2010" IN BOOLEAN MODE)`

Issues:

- `FULLTEXT` has a minimum word length; either change that (alas, it is a global setting) or deal with short "words" differently.  If, say, the min word len is 3, then remove th '+' from before 'q5' in the `AGAINST` string.  Otherwise, InnoDB will find no rows.
- Similarly deal with "stop words".  Or remove the stop list.
- Deal with hyphenated, etc, words in some way.
- It may help to do `ORDER BY MATCH ... LIMIT 20` to (1) give some preference to the oddball cases, and (2) limit the output when the user does not specify enough.
- Or you might want to play fair and do `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20`.

If you are using 5.7 or MariaDB, a "generated" column may be useful.

Comment: I will mark your response as accepted since it's almost solve my problem and can help other with similar problem. It's a good start to learn more about `WHERE MATCH() AGAINST`.